# Parameter passing via httpgetClient

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to hit the URL and get the response, but through this method I can get only one message whereas I want to pass multiple values as a response.

Here is the method:

```
public String getOutputFromUrl(String url) 
    {
        Log.d("in getOutputFromUrl", "getOutputFromUrl");
        String[] output = null;
        try {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.d("in UnsupportedEncodingException", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("in geClientProtocolExceptiontOutputFromUrl",  e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("in getOutputFromUrl", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("in getOutputFromUrl:output===>>", output);

        return output;
     }
```

I want the return type of the method to be String[] or object of any class ,but

```
 output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)
```

This line accepts only a string; no other object or string array, so I can't keep multiple values in this output variable passed as response from the URL link

Comment: @Bruno von Paris : hi , i am new to stackoverflow , and i dont understand what bounty is , is it something bad or good ??

Comment: Yes, bounties are good. When you have enough reputation points, you can associate a bounty to a question (you question or someone else question). It is a kind of reward to the person who will successfully answer. You can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation